# Processing a 40MB+ object in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, callstack

I have a bit of an unusual situation involving some 179586 bookmarks in chrome.  Most of these are duplicates, and I need to remove those.

Obviously, this process would need to be automated with a script..

Chrome's bookmarks API enforces a draconian quota on the permitted rate of manipulation ops, so I must first export the data into a format that is more conducive to offline manipulation.

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(t){tree = t[0]});
```

stores the entire repository under the global variable `tree`, in the [`BookmarkTreeNode` format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#type-BookmarkTreeNode).

```
JSON.stringify(tree).length;
```

shows that the object, at least with JSON encoding, is `42777359` bytes long.

```
JSON.stringify(tree).match(/"url"/g).length
```

shows that in total, there are `179586` bookmarks.

So, to flatten the whole thing:

```
var ALL = [], stack = [];
function processTree(tree) {
  if(!(!tree.url != !tree.children)) throw tree;

  var entry = (tree.url ? [tree.url, tree.title] : ["FOLDER", tree.title]).concat(stack);
  entry.dateAdded = tree.dateAdded;

  ALL.push(entry);

  if(tree.children) {
    stack.unshift(tree.title);
    tree.children.forEach(processTree);
    stack.shift();
  }

  return 'done.';
}
```

Unfortunately, not only do I not get the expected result from this, but I also get: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.  When I inspect `ALL` and `stack`, they both appear to be Arrays of length 17388.  `stack` consists of exclusively empty strings, while `ALL` consists exclusively of arrays which consist exclusively of empty strings.

Anyone have any tips for how to approach this problem? Perhaps Node.js is a more suitable environment than the Chrome dev console for the processing phase, and I should just be focusing on getting the JSON out of there, at this point?

Maybe Node has a more flexible and configurable callstack limit and other such parameters?

Thanks for any thoughts! :)

Comment: I'll look into trampolining, but how could I make it nonrecursive without knowing the maximum depth of the folders?

Comment: Isn't this recursing infinitely? You're always passing the same tree.

Comment: ahh, so i am! lemme try with it fixed..

Comment: @bfavaretto yup, that was it! thanks very much :)